# Delete All Files Older Than Specified Time Within A Directory (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, command-line, rm

I have a bunch of files in a directory with all different names and I want to delete all that are older than a specified time.

Example:

```
File1
File2
File3

File1 was made Mar 31 08:00
File2 was made Mar 31 08:01
File3 was made Mar 31 08:05
```

I want to delete everything that was created before Mar 31 08:04 in one directory.

Also the create date is the last modified date they never change they are never being updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming there are only regular files and no funny things like subdirectories or other file like objects.

```
find -not -newermt "Mar 31 08:04" -delete
```

To see which files are going to be deleted run without `-delete` first.

`-not -newermt` means to find files which modification time is older than the given time string.

The time string is parsed like the `date` tool does. You can test your time string like this:

```
date -R -d "Mar 31 08:04"
```

output on my system:

```
Tue, 31 Mar 2015 08:04:00 +0200
```

If `date` refuses your string so will `find -newermt`.

Note that `date` (and therefore `find`) also accepts some natural language time expression like "2 weeks ago" or "1 month ago".

For more information read the man page of `find` and `date`. The explanation for the option `-newermt` is listed under `-newerXY` in the man page.

Comment: You're amazing and thank you the explanation.  This can be used for so much.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make the story full, because when we want to delete all files older than a specified time within a directory, then that specified time is better specified as for e.g. two-week old or one-month old, instead of specifying a fixed date string.

If so, let me present, a ready made Ubuntu package -- `tmpreaper`:

Description: cleans up files in directories based on their age

This package provides a program that can be used to clean out temporary-file
 directories.  It recursively searches the directory, refusing to chdir()
 across symlinks, and removes files that haven't been accessed in a
 user-specified amount of time.  You can specify a set of files to protect
 from deletion with a shell pattern.  It will not remove files owned by the
 process EUID that have the `w` bit clear, unless you ask it to, much like
 `rm -f`.  `tmpreaper' will not remove symlinks, sockets, fifos, or special
 files unless given a command line option enabling it to.